# Elasticsearch & Docker permissions issue

Tags: docker, elasticsearch

I'm trying to run ElasticSearch with docker-compose, but it's not going well

docker-compose.yml

```
es:
    image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
    ports:
     - "9200:9200"
     - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      - "discovery.type=single-node"
    volumes:
     - ./elasticsearch_data:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

Error after starting up
 `"stacktrace": ["org.elasticsearch.bootstrap.StartupException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: failed to obtain node locks, tried [[/usr/share/elasticsearch/data]] with lock id [0]; maybe these locations are not writable or multiple nodes were started without increasing [node.max_local_storage_nodes] (was [1])?",`

Even I run it without local volume, it throws exactly the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Under your volume section, set the volume to another place which is accessible by your user. This will fix that error.

```
es:
image: docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:7.6.2
ports:
 - "9200:9200"
 - "9300:9300"
environment:
  - "discovery.type=single-node"
volumes:
 - ./elasticsearch_data:/home/myuser/elasticsearch/data
```